# ORA-01861: Literal does not match format string - WHEN querying a VIEW - but it's NOT a DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on ORACLE 10g.

I try to query some fields of a view, but in sqlplus I get ora-01861 in simple SELECT-statement like

```
SELECT PREIS FROM VLBABGL
```

(where VLBABGL is the name of the view), not to say the UPDATE-Statement I'd try to run.

The fields I use are not fields of DATE-type. They both are defined as VARCHAR2 and contain numbers (field "MEDIENNR", e.g. 0585743) and prices (field "PREIS") with comma (00,00). If I query the same view in SQL Developer 4, there are no errors.

The field "PREIS" contains data which I split from the source-field "ISBN_ZUS". There it is stored like "fest geb. : 19,99" an I split the field with `regexp_substr(m.isbn_zus, '[[:digit:]]{1,3},[[:digit:]]{2}') PREIS`. The field "MEDIENNR" is as it is in the source-field. And if I query the field "MEDIENNR" of the source-table, I get no error in sqlplus.

Has anyone an idea what might be the problem here?

The code of the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "BV"."VLBABGL" ("MEDIENNR", "TITEL", "ISBN", "ISBN_ZUS", "PREIS", "EINBAND") AS 
  SELECT DISTINCT
  m.mediennr AS MEDIENNR,
  m.HST AS TITEL,
  (SELECT regexp_replace(ISBN, '-', '') FROM MEDIEN WHERE ISBN like '978-3%' AND mediennr = m.mediennr)  AS ISBN,
  m.isbn_zus AS ISBN_ZUS,
  regexp_substr(m.isbn_zus, '[[:digit:]]{1,3},[[:digit:]]{2}') PREIS,
  regexp_substr(m.isbn_zus, '.[a-z.3 ]{1,10}') EINBAND
FROM MEDIEN m, HISTORY h, ZUSFELDERVALUES zv
WHERE (m.mediennr = h.idnr AND zv.table_key = m.mediennr)
AND h.upddate > '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
AND m.geschgang > '6'
AND (zv.FELDNAME = 'Stichworte' AND zv.value IS NOT NULL);
```

And because I mentioned in a comment below a table which contains also a field "PREIS" which I can adress with sqlplus without errormessage, I also post the definition of this table. As you may presume, I have to compare both prices.

```
create table VLB (
      ISBN VARCHAR2(20),
      EAN VARCHAR2 (20),
      TITEL VARCHAR2(1000),
      PRODUKTART VARCHAR2(10),
      AKTION VARCHAR2(10),
      L_AEND VARCHAR2 (10),
      PREIS VARCHAR2(10),
      P_GUELTIG_BIS VARCHAR2(12),
      P_GUELTIG_AB VARCHAR2(12),
      KOMMENTAR VARCHAR2(255),
      PREISTYP VARCHAR2 (40) 
)
;
```

And her also the definition of the source-table of the fields "MEDIENNR" AND "PREIS" (which is "ISBN_ZUS"). Because it's a huge one, I copy only the parts which point to the fields questioned here.

```
CREATE TABLE "BV"."MEDIEN" 
   (    "MEDIENNR" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 ...
    "ISBN_ZUS" VARCHAR2(160 BYTE), 
 ...
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 303038464 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BV" ;

 ...
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "BV"."MEDIEN_PRIM" ON "BV"."MEDIEN" ("MEDIENNR") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 9437184 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BV" ;

  CREATE INDEX "BV"."TEMP1" ON "BV"."MEDIEN" ("GT_SUCH", "MEDIENNR") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 10485760 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BV" ;


  CREATE INDEX "BV"."TEMP2" ON "BV"."MEDIEN" ("GT2_SUCH", "MEDIENNR") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 10485760 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BV" ;

... ;
```

Comment: Please post the code of the view. Also, here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The number starts with a zero - if this was in a `NUMBER` type column then the leading zero would not be stored. For many uses this is acceptable but there are cases where the leading zero has semantic meaning and should be retained.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The point is that there is data which is a string comprised of numeric characters and all of those characters have some semantic meaning - to convert it to a number risks eliminating some of these characters (leading zeroes) which may result in the software making assumptions when returning the numeric value to its expected string value. Take for an example an ISBNs - there are 9-digit SBNs, 10-digit ISBNs (pre 2007) and 13-digit ISBNs (post 2007) and storing it as a number risks confusing an SBN with an ISBN with leading zeros.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, @MT0 - Thanks so far. The tablespace I have to deal with is the tablespace of a program called Bibliotheca. It uses numbers of different length to differentiate between users and media. Users have numbers of 6 digits and media 7. That's why the leading 0 is important. So I can't change the type of the field "MEDIENNR", but if I understand you right @a_horse_with_no_name, I have to convert the column "PREIS" into number. But - excuse the silly question - can I define columns in a view? (eg. `PREIS DECIMAL`) and use the comma as separator if nls_numeric_characters is ',.'.

Comment: You need to show us the definition of the view (and of the  underlying tables)

Comment: If the format of the field is the problem, I don't understand, why sqlplus querries the second "PREIS"-field in another table - which is also VARCHAR2 without error. You asked for the view definition and I add the definiton of the table mentioned in the question.

Comment: Looks like you don't need our help. Provide definition of table AND the view and you will get help.

Comment: What data type is `HISTORY.upddate`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: I provided the code as asked: the view, parts of the code of the source-table and the code of the second table which contains a field "PREIS". But I forgot one word in my last comment: "and I added the definition of the table, too."

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: HISTORY.upddate is DATE ... and I guess this might be the source of the problem, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the view:

```
AND h.upddate > '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
```

is your problem (because `upddate` is a `DATE` column).

This condition relies on the evil implicit data type conversion which is subject to the NLS settings of the **client** querying the view.

SQL Developer and SQL*Plus are using different NLS settings and that's why your query fails in one environment but not in another.

That line should be changed to

```
AND h.upddate > to_date('2010-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you! Shame on me, I only saw the visible columns of the view when I searched for the error-reason (?), but haven't had in mind, that the views is based amongst others on a DATE-condition. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Chris: you might also revisit the condition `AND m.geschgang > '6'`

Comment: `m.geschgang` is of type VARCHAR2. I altered `'6'` to 6, but then the view is empty.

Comment: @chris: if that is a varchar, then you don't need to change it.